# ground truth fit is worse than cross validated fit on noisy data?

Tags: python, cross-validation, least-squares

I am having these weird results when playing around with cross validation that I would greatly appreciate to have any comments.

Briefly, I have a lower mean squared error (MSE) when doing regression (least-squares) using cross-valitation (CV), than when using the "ground truth weights" that I used to generate the data.

Note however, that I compute the MSE on noisy data (generated data + noise), so MSE of 0 would not be expected for noise levels above 0.

Weirdly, for high noise conditions, I get lower MSE with cross validated least squares than with the "ground" truth weights used to generate the clean data - to which I then add different levels of noise to the input (X). Instead, if I add guassian noise to the output (y) the "ground truth weights" perform better.

More details below.

### Simulation of data

I am generating **beta** from a guassian and **X** from a uniform distribution. I then compute the to-be-regressed **y** as y = beta * X.
python 3 code:

```
def generate_data(noise_frac):
  X = np.random.rand(ntrials,nneurons)
  X = np.random.normal(size=(ntrials,nneurons))
  
  beta = np.random.randn(nneurons)
  y = X @ beta

  # not very important how I generated noise here
  noise_x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=zeros(nneurons), cov=diag(np.random.rand(nneurons)), size=ntrials)

                            
  X_noise = X + noise_x*noise_frac

  return X_noise, y, beta
```

As you can see I also add noise to **X**.

## Regression

I then project this noised data **X_noise** for different values of **noise** onto **beta**:

```
y_hat = (X_noise) @ beta
```

And compute the MSE:

```
mse = mean((y_hat - y)**2)
```

As expected, MSE increases with noise (blue line in the figure).

[image: MSE for CV and ground truth beta weights]

However, I get lower MSE if I use cross validated least-squares! This is now orange line in the figure.

To do CV, I split **X_noise** in random 100 train and test sets. In broad terms, This is how I do CV in python:

```
beta_lsq = pinv(X_train) @ y_train
y_hat_lsq = (X_test) @ beta_lsq
mse = mean((y_hat_lsq - y_test)**2)
```

On the other hand, if I add noise to y, instead of X, then everything makes sense:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

PS: This is a crosspost from stack overflow

Comment: here's a link to a notebook to reproduce this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lTwRCwEP3uzhi6c4rAN-gJs6_XEszgc6?usp=sharing

Comment: the mentioned cross-post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77224/55122